# Kaltura open source player does not play video in Android webview

Tags: android, webview, kaltura

I am loading a webpage inside Android WebView, the webpage has video playback using Kultura's open source video player. The same webpage plays the video fine if opened through a normal phone browser but on webview there is no playback and it continuously keeps on showing the loader.

This issue is being seen only on samsung android devices. The webpage has authenticated access therefore cant share the webpage. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue, turns out I had to simply provide a custom implementation of WebChromeClient and now the videos magically plays:

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){});
```